# C# Windows form How can I add previously entered intput to new input?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a form that allows the user to input an employee's name, pay-rate, and hours worked for a pay period. Once that info is entered into the three text-boxes, the user clicks a button that calculates gross pay, social security withheld, medicare withheld, state taxes withheld, Federal taxes withheld, and net pay. This info is output to a label. I want the user to be able to enter multiple employees, and have this information added to previous input (if the first employee had a gross pay of $2,000.00 and the second employee had a gross pay of $1,000, the total gross pay is $3,000, etc.) How might I go about accomplishing this?

Current code:

```
public Employees()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name;
        decimal hours, payrate, grosspay;
        Boolean error = false;

        name = NameBox.Text;
        if (NameBox.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter a full name into the name textbox.");
            error = true;
            NameBox.Focus();
        }
        hours = decimal.Parse(HoursWorkedBox.Text);
        payrate = decimal.Parse(HourRateBox.Text);
        if (hours < 0 || payrate < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot have negative hours/hourly rate.");
            error = true;
            HoursWorkedBox.Focus();
        }


        if (error == false)
        {
            decimal netpay, sswithheld, mcwithheld, statetaxwithheld, fedtaxwithheld;
            grosspay = hours * payrate;
            sswithheld = grosspay * .061m;
            mcwithheld = grosspay * .0143m;
            statetaxwithheld = 0;
            fedtaxwithheld = 0;
            if (grosspay > 0 && grosspay < 600)
            {
                statetaxwithheld = grosspay * .02m;
                fedtaxwithheld = grosspay * .05m;
            }
            else if (grosspay >= 600 && grosspay < 1100)
            {
                statetaxwithheld = grosspay * .04m;
                fedtaxwithheld = grosspay * .10m;
            }
            else if (grosspay >= 1100 && grosspay < 1600)
            {
                statetaxwithheld = grosspay * .06m;
                fedtaxwithheld = grosspay * .15m;
            }
            else if (grosspay >= 1600 && grosspay < 2100)
            {
                statetaxwithheld = grosspay * .06m;
                fedtaxwithheld = grosspay * .20m;
            }
            else if (grosspay >= 2100 && grosspay < 3100)
            {
                statetaxwithheld = grosspay * .06m;
                fedtaxwithheld = grosspay * .25m;
            }
            else if (grosspay > 3100)
            {
                statetaxwithheld = grosspay * .06m;
                fedtaxwithheld = grosspay * .30m;
            }
            netpay = grosspay - fedtaxwithheld - statetaxwithheld - sswithheld - mcwithheld;
            OutputLbl.Text = ("Employee name: " + name + "\nGross pay: " + grosspay + "\nFederal Tax Withheld : " + fedtaxwithheld + "\nState Tax Withheld: " + statetaxwithheld + "\nSocial Security Withheld: " + sswithheld + "\nMedicare Withheld: " + mcwithheld + "\nNet Pay: " + netpay);

        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is.  Are you asking for something like: `OutputLbl.Text  += ("Employee name: " + name + "\nGross pay: " + grosspay + "\nFederal Tax Withheld : " + fedtaxwithheld + "\nState Tax Withheld: " + statetaxwithheld + "\nSocial Security Withheld: " + sswithheld + "\nMedicare Withheld: " + mcwithheld + "\nNet Pay: " + netpay);`

Comment: Notice the `+=`

Comment: What happens to this? `OutputLbl.Text = ("Employee name: " + name + "\nGross pay: " + grosspay + "\nFederal Tax Withheld : " + fedtaxwithheld + "\nState Tax Withheld: " + statetaxwithheld + "\nSocial Security Withheld: " + sswithheld + "\nMedicare Withheld: " + mcwithheld + "\nNet Pay: " + netpay);
`

Comment: As my code is now, i calculate the gross/net pay of one employee. I want to be able to do this for multiple employees, and add their pay info to a different label, which keeps track of the Total payment info for all employees I have entered.

Comment: @glr22 if what you're asking is really that simple, then my comment above should do it for you.

Comment: @mydogisbox That allows me to enter new employees and keep the old info, but does not add the info to a total. I want to add the gross/net pay and all the other info together in a Total label. So if Dan Smith has a gross pay of $1000 and Sally Ann has a gross pay of $2000, the total gross pay is $3000. I want to do this with all the other fields too (except for the name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways but just off the top of my head I would make a Controller possibly or the likes of and have it store a list of Employee classes where the Employee class has all the information for each employee.  Then you can find the running total of all employees from the Controller (EmployeeController maybe) by simply adding up the gross from the list.

Quick and ugly example (Edit Employee and EmployeeController to fit your needs):

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Pay { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeController
{
     private static EmployeeController employeeController = new EmployeeController();
     private { Employees = new List<Employee>(); }
     public static EmployeeController Instance => employeeController;

     public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

     public double TotalPay
     {
         get
         {
               var totalPay = 0d;

               foreach (var employee in Employees)
                    totalPay += employee.Pay;

               return totalPay;
         }
     }
}
```

Then you can use it like so...

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
     var newEmployee = new Employee() 
     {
          Name = textboxName.Text,
          Pay = double.Parse(textboxPay.Text)
     }

     EmployeeController.Instance.Employees.Add(newEmployee);

     labelEmployeePay.Text = newEmployee.Pay;
     labelTotalPay.Text = EmployeeController.Instance.TotalPay;
}
```

Comment: Your right, this is pretty ugly.... appreciate your help, but I can't seem to make sense of it. Know of any resources that may help with learning to do this type of thing?

Comment: I don't mind helping.  It's a common method for programming though.  Just think in terms of allowing the Controller to manage the data (in this situation) as opposed to the form.